# insmod: error inserting 'usb338x.ko': -1 Unknown symbol in module

Tags: linux, usb, linux-device-driver, usb-drive

I compiled a driver then tried to load de module and this is the return

```
insmod: error inserting 'usb338x.ko': -1 Unknown symbol in module
```

and dmesg

```
[ 8128.506098] usb338x: Unknown symbol usb_add_gadget_udc (err 0)
[ 8128.506116] usb338x: Unknown symbol usb_gadget_unmap_request (err 0)
[ 8128.506127] usb338x: Unknown symbol usb_del_gadget_udc (err 0)
[ 8128.506138] usb338x: Unknown symbol usb_gadget_map_request (err 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reading other post i realized that i need to load the udc_core

```
modprobe udc_core
```

thats it!

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try this : `MODULE_LICENSE("GPL")` add to your kernel module file.